# How to ask "Is your name common in Japan?"

Tags: names, questions, english-to-japanese

> きみのなわ。。。。ですか。

How can I fill the gap?

Comment: We don't do translation. You have to show use your full attempt before. I think that きみのな is not the best option out there to say "your name" because it would be rather weird in a casual context.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm really new here so I don't know much. I will take notice.

Answer (score 4):

If I were to choose a one-word expression, that would be a na-adjective 普通【ふつう】.

> あなたの 名前【なまえ】は 普通【ふつう】ですか？

- Use は instead of わ when it's the topic marker. It's still pronounced as *wa*.
- 名【な】 is a literary and/or pompous way of saying "name". Use 名前【なまえ】 instead.
- I also replaced the casual second-person pronoun きみ with あなた, because きみ is rarely used with polite expressions (e.g. ですか).

However the sentence above may sound a bit rude because it sounds like you are talking whether a name is *normal* or *abnormal*, rather than *common* or *uncommon*.

(**EDIT**: There is another na-adjective [一般的【いっぱんてき】](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%80%E8%88%AC%E7%9A%84), which may be more difficult but safer. "あなたの名前は一般的ですか？")

Alternatively, you can say something like this:

> あなたの 名前【なまえ】は よく ある 名前ですか？
>   (lit. "Is your name a name that exists often?")
>
> あなたの 名前【なまえ】は よく 見【み】る 名前ですか？
>   (lit. "Is your name a name that you see often?")

Technically speaking, this よくある is a [relative clause](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/clause) that modifies 名前 right *after* it, but you may regard it as a set phrase that just means "common". For example, "Frequently Asked Question" is often translated as "よくある質問【しつもん】" in Japanese.